# invalid-function in emacs 26 but works in emacs 25

Tags: emacs, optional-parameters, emacs26

This works in emacs 25:

```
(setq custom-keymap (copy-keymap global-map))

(defun custom-def (keys func &optional file &optional global-p)
  (define-key custom-keymap keys func)
  (if global-p (global-set-key keys func))
  (if file (autoload func file "[custom autoload]" t)))

(custom-def [delete] 'delete-char)
```

But when I call `custom-def` in emacs 26 I get an `invalid-function` error. I isolated it to the `&optional` parameters. I removed those two args and `custom-def` works.

So what changed between 25 and 26? What am I missing here? I want the flexible ARGLIST that works in emacs 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `optional` just once in the parameter list- the following parameters will all be optional [other keywords can follow as well - see [info(elisp) Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html)].

```
(defun custom-def (keys func &optional file global-p)
  ;; ...
  )
```

[I'm not sure what the change was - perhaps duplicated parameter checking was added?]

Comment: D'oh. I had never tried compiling that function. Emacs 25 allows it, but Emacs 26 tells me exactly what I did: `Error: Duplicate &optional`